# How to make this function check if elements in array(table1) are the same ? It works with numbers but not strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, typeof

Function is checking if elements inside array are the same

```
function isUniform(){
var table1 = ['a','b','a','a'];
for(var y = table1.length - 1; y>=0; y--){
    if( (typeof table1 === 'string' && table1[y] !== table1[y - 1]) || (typeof table1 !== 'string' && table1[y] !== table1[y - 1] && table1[y - 1] >0) ){
        return false;
    }
}
return true;}
```

it should return false

edit: thanks everyone for help !

Comment: Why so many checks? What is `table1[y - 1] >0` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are checking the element at index `y-1` is greater than `0`. You should check of for the index not element at that index.

```js
function isUniform(table1){
  for(var y = table1.length - 1; y>=0; y--){
    if( (typeof table1 === 'string' && table1[y] !== table1[y -   1]) || (typeof table1 !== 'string' && table1[y] !== table1[y  - 1] && y - 1 > 0) ){
        return false;
    }
  }
return true;
}
console.log(isUniform(['a','b','a','a']))
```

#### Using `Set()`

A simpler way to do that is using `Set()`

```js
const allEqual = arr => new Set(arr).size === 1 
console.log(allEqual(['a','b','a','a']))
```

#### Using `every()`

You can also use `every()` and compare each element with first one.

```js
const allEqual = arr => arr.every(x => arr[0] === x);
console.log(allEqual(['a','b','a','a']))
```

**Note:** A function like this usually takes a parameter and then return based on that input. You are are not supposed to declare a local array and then only test on it.

Secondly I couldnot understand the reason for `typeof table1 === 'string'`. If you would explain what are other requirements of function you will get a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could just check the first item with each other item.

```js
function isUniform(array) {
    var i,
        first = array[0];
 
    for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (first !== array[i]) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

console.log(isUniform(['a', 'b', 'a', 'a']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code by using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). From docs,

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

```js
function isUniform() {
  var table = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a'];
  return new Set(table).size === 1;
}

console.log(isUniform());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isUniform (table) {
  var first = table.shift();
  return !table.find((item) => {
    return item !== first;
  });
}

var table = ["a", "b", "a", "a"];
isUniform(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table.every( item => item === table[0] )`

```js
function isUniform(table){
 return table.every( item => item === table[0] )
 //return test;
}


var table1 = ['a','b','a','a'];
console.log(isUniform(table1))
```